# What is the semicolon in C++?

Tags: c++

Roughly speaking in C++ there are:

- operators (`+`, `-`, `*`, `[]`, `new`, `...`)
- identifiers (names of classes, variables, functions,...)
- const literals (`10`, `2.5`, `"100"`, ...)
- some keywords (`int`, `class`, `typename`, `mutable`, ...)
- brackets (`{`, `}`, `<`, `>`)
- preprocessor (`#`, `##` ...).

But what is the semicolon?

Comment: I'm not sure about C++, but in most grammars it's just a *terminal symbol* (generally either statement terminator or in constructs like `for`, etc.) without a special name. (If it is given a name, it often depends upon context.)

Comment: also what about multiple semicolons tied together as in ;;;;; why?

Comment: @jujanes - we also have the empty statement, which contains nothing but is still terminated by a semicolon.

Comment: "const literals"... as if there are non-const literals out there :)

Comment: @Bo Persson Not according to the standard (C++03, anyway).  There is no empty statement.  There is an empty expression, however, and a simple `;`, with nothing in front of it, is an expression statement, with an empty expression.  Which is only legal in contexts where an expression statement is legal: not in namespace scope, for example.  (C++11 adds an empty declaration, which makes empty "statements" legal everywhere.  And most compilers allowed them even before that.)

Comment: See 2.13 [lex.operators]. That table lists the tokns that are recognized specially during preprocessing, which includes ';'. Each member of that table is converted into either an operator or a punctuator when preprocessing tokens are converted into C++ tokens. There is no separate table for punctuators, because there is a table for operators, and punctuators follow from that and the other table.

Comment: @James saying "empty statement" is more to the truth than "empty expression". The real thing is called "null statement", and the spec says "An expression statement with the expression missing is called a null statement.". Hence, what is "empty" is the statement, not the expression. The latter is absent. It strikes me as being argumentative though. You can always argue that neither the expression nor the statement is empty. Something that is absent cannot be empty, and something that contains a ';' cannot be empty either, can it?

Comment: The fact that C++0x calls a declaration solely consisting of ';' an "empty declaration" however shows that calling a null statement an "empty statement" as used by @BoPersson isn't all that off.

Comment: @Johannes The grammar of C++03 does not have a production `empty-statement` (nor `null-statement`, for that matter).  The actual words used aren't that important, as long as one keeps in mind that a "null statement" or an "empty statement" or whatever is a convenient word for an empty expression statement, and that it can only appear in the context where an expression statement is legal.  C++11 adds an `empty-declaration`, which does correspond very exactly to what I understand by "empty statement" (but it's still not officially an `empty-statement`).

Comment: @James My quote above is a direct standard quote, and it defines what is called a "null statement". "The actual words used aren't that important" I do agree to this however. As long as it is clear what is meant. My complaint was with you saying that "There is no empty statement ... [but] there is an empty expression".

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The semicolon is a *punctuator*, see 2.13 §1

> The lexical representation of C++ programs includes a number of preprocessing tokens which are used in
>   the syntax of the preprocessor or are converted into tokens for operators and **punctuators**

Answer (score 14):

It is part of the syntax and therein element of several statements. In [EBNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form):

```
<do-statement>
    ::= 'do' <statement> 'while' '(' <expression> ')' ';'

<goto-statement>
    ::= 'goto' <label> ';'

<for-statement>
    ::= 'for' '(' <for-initialization> ';' <for-control> ';' <for-iteration> ')' <statement>

<expression-statement>
    ::= <expression> ';'

<return-statement>
    ::= 'return' <expression> ';'
```

This list is not complete. Please see my comment.

Comment: Beautiful. And now the declarations, definitions and all the other stuff where the semicolon is used. ;)

Comment: Declarations and definitions (I guess assignments) are expressions and hence covered by this list. I don't think there are more uses for the semicolon in C++. But please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @Hyper: Since when are class declarations expressions? (Genuine question)

Comment: @Xeo. You are completely right. The (now hopefully complete) list of syntactic elements using the semicolon are: asm_definition / expression_statement / iteration_statement / jump_statement / member_declaration / namespace_alias_definition / preprocessing_op_or_punc / simple_declaration / using_declaration / using_directive

Comment: The grammar of the `for`-statement is incorrect. The `for-initialization` is already a declaration, and brings its own `;`. The `for-control` part is an expression, though, so the second `;` is correct.

Comment: Why must the for initialization be a declaration? What with `for(;;);` or `for(init();check();inc())do();`?

Answer (score 7):

The semicolon is a terminal, a token that terminates something. What exactly it terminates depends on the context.

Answer (score 6):

Semicolon denotes sequential composition.  It is also used to delineate declarations.

Comment: +1 the lack of upvotes indicates that few programmers really understand the meanings of the symbols and expressions in programming languages.

Answer (score 6):

Semicolon is a statement terminator.

Answer (score 1):

The semicolon isn't given a specific name in the C++ standard.  It's simply a character that's used in certain grammar productions (and it just happens to be at the end of them quite often, so it 'terminates' those grammatical constructs).  For example, a semicolon character is at the end of the following parts of the C++ grammar (not necessarily a complete list):

- an `expression-statement`
- a do/while `iteration-statement`
- the various `jump-statement`s
- the `simple-declaration`

Note that in an `expression-statement`, the expression is optional. That's why a 'run' of semicolons, `;;;;`, is valid in many (but not all) places where a single one is.

Answer (score 1):

';'s are often used to delimit one bit of C++ source code, indicating it's intentionally separate from the following code.  To see how it's useful, let's imagine we didn't use it:

For example:

```
#include <iostream>

int f() { std::cout << "f()\n"; }
int g() { std::cout << "g()\n"; }

int main(int argc)
{
    std::cout << "message"

    "\0\1\0\1\1"[argc] ? f() : g();  // final ';' needed to make this compile
                                     // but imagine it's not there in this new
                                     // semicolon-less C++ variant....
}
```

This (horrible) bit of code, called with no arguments such that `argc` is `1`, prints:

```
ef()\n
```

Why not "messagef()\n"?  That's what might be expected given first `std::cout << "message"`, then `"\0\1\0\1\1"[1]` being `'\1'` - `true` in a boolean sense - suggests a call to `f()` printing `f()\n`?

Because... (drumroll please)... in C++ adjacent string literals are concatenated, so the program's parsed like this:

```
std::cout << "message\0\1\0\1\1"[argc] ? f() : g();
```

What this does is:

- find the `[argc/1]` (second) character in "message\0\1\0\1\1", which is the first 'e'
- send that 'e' to `std::cout` (printing it)
- the ternary operator '?' triggers casting of `std::cout` to `bool` which produces `true` (because the printing presumably worked), so `f()` is called...!

Given this string literal concatenation is incredibly useful for specifying long strings
(and even shorter multi-line strings in a readable format), we certainly wouldn't want to assume that such strings shouldn't be concatenated.  Consequently, if the semicolon's gone then the compiler must assume the concatenation is intended, even though visually the layout of the code above implies otherwise.

That's a convoluted example of how C++ code with and with-out ';'s changes meaning.  I'm sure if I or other readers think on it for a few minutes we could come up with other - and simpler - examples.

Anyway, the ';' is *necessary* to inform the compiler that statement termination/separation is intended.

Answer (score 0):

The semicolon lets the compiler know that it's reached the end of a command AFAIK.

Comment: what about:
`int a, b = \n
        a = x`

Comment: Not a good answer. The relevant C++ constructs are 'statements' and 'expressions', not 'commands'.

Answer (score 0):

The semicolon (;) is a command in C++. It tells the compiler that you're at the end of a command.

Comment: Not a good answer. The relevant C++ constructs are 'statements' and 'expressions', not 'commands'.

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correctly, Kernighan and Ritchie called it punctuation.
Technically, it's just a token (or terminal, in compiler-speak), which
can occur in specific places in the grammar, with a specific semantics
in the language.  The distinction between operators and other punctuation
is somewhat artificial, but useful in the context of C or C++, since
some tokens (`,`, `=` and `:`) can be either operators or punctuation,
depending on context, e.g.:

```
f( a, b );      //  comma is punctuation
f( (a, b) );    //  comma is operator
a = b;          //  = is assignment operator
int a = b;      //  = is punctuation
x = c ? a : b;  //  colon is operator
label:          //  colon is punctuation
```

In the case of the first two, the distinction is important, since a user
defined overload will only affect the operator, not punctuation.

Answer (score 0):

It represents the end of a C++ statement.

For example,

```
 int i=0;
 i++;
```

In the above code there are two statements. The first is for declaring the variable and the second one is for incrementing the value of variable by one.