# Should I add a semi-colon at the end of a include statement?

Tags: c++, include

In C++ I'm not sure if I'm supposed to add a semi-colon at the end of a include statement or not.
For example, to use the `std::cout` method you must include the `iostream` library, like this:

```
#include <iostream>
```

After I include the `<iostream>` library should I add semi-colon at the end of the statement, like this:

```
#include <iostream>;
```

Or just leave it be?

Comment: There is no reason for adding a semi colon after an include statement. There are many places you can put semi colons that are legal but meaningless.

Comment: related/dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10011318/why-include-directive-doesnt-have-a-semi-colon-at-the-end-of-statement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No you shouldn't.**

---

**Why?**

`#xxxxxx` are **preprocessor directives**. The former are part of a separate step in the compilation process. The preprocessor analyses the code before the actual compilation of code starts. All the directives are resolved before actual code is generated by normal C++ statements.

Summary:

- Most C/C++ statements need to be ended with a semicolon `;`. It's part of the [C/C++ standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6464436/what-is-the-semicolon-in-c).
- Preprocessor directives do not need to be ended by a `;` or any other symbol.

Comment: Ok. Agreed. Thanks for heads up @FrançoisAndrieux. There's also some statements that can optionally be ended with ";", e.g closing braces.

Comment: Sure-empty statements are legal. Silly, but legal. It's not that you're ending a block with an "optional semicolon" rather you're offering empty statements.

Answer (score 1):

If the content of the include file is syntactically correct, the semicolon will have no effect at all. So why should you add it? Redundant code like this typically causes confusion and leads to bad maintainability.

In the unlikely case that a semicolon is missing after the last statement of your include file, this error would be 'fixed' by adding the semicolon. But this is by no means a good thing because such an error should be fixed in the include file itself. Otherwise it will lead to even more confusion.